# How to select a column value based on two row conditions?

Tags: php, mysql

```
Name      Username    Day worked  Time period  
----------------------------------------------
John Doe  john        Sunday      8
Tom       tom         Monday      10
Jane Doe  jane        Tuesday     5
John Doe  john        Friday      9
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT username FROM table WHERE (day_worked='Sunday' AND time_period>5) AND (day_worked='Friday' and time_period>8)
```

Here I am applying conditions for two columns, user who worked on Sunday more than 5 hours and Friday more than 8 hours. So obviously John Doe (Username: john) meets the condition and it should be outputted.

However this does not return anything. May be the logic I am using is wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Try : SELECT username FROM table WHERE (day_worked='Sunday' AND time_period>5) OR (day_worked='Friday' and time_period>8)

Comment: @Dharmang: It must be AND coupled. I need users who worked both on Sunday and Friday not on any single day alone.

Comment: @Dharmang He needs both. the OR would match either one of the cases. I don't think it's what he is looking for. I don't think his table example is the best example. He could have the same username multiple times, for different days and hours. He wants to know WHO worked on Friday over 8 hours AND Sunday over 5 hours, not either day.

Comment: ok, it is confusing, but I now got it. thanks.

Comment: What I thought in simple terms that, day_worked = 'Sunday' AND day_worked = 'Friday' will always return empty result set.

Comment: It's still OR though! It's what happens next that solves the conundrum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by a bit of cross-tabulation magic. First off, cross tabulate all of your users by Sunday and Friday:

```
SELECT
  username,
  SUM(CASE WHEN `Day worked` = 'Sunday' THEN `Time Period` END) As Sunday,
  SUM(CASE WHEN `Day worked` = 'Friday' THEN `Time Period` END) AS Friday
FROM table
GROUP BY username
```

This query will yield the following:

```
username  Sunday  Friday
--------  ------  ------
jane      NULL    NULL
john      8       9
tom       NULL    NULL
```

By pushing this result down into a subquery you can easily pick out who worked more than 5 hours on Sunday and more than 8 hours on Friday:

```
 SELECT username
 FROM (
   SELECT
     username,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `Day worked` = 'Sunday' THEN `Time Period` END) As Sunday,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `Day worked` = 'Friday' THEN `Time Period` END) AS Friday
    FROM table
    GROUP BY username
  ) SunFri
WHERE SunFri.Sunday > 5 AND SunFri.Friday > 8
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT username 
  FROM table 
 WHERE (day_worked='Sunday' AND time_period>5)         
    OR (day_worked='Friday' and time_period>8) 
 GROUP 
    BY username
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if this query is gives you the desired result

```
SELECT username FROM table 
INNER JOIN table T2 ON table.Username = T2.Username AND (day_worked='Friday' and time_period>8)
WHERE (day_worked='Sunday' AND time_period>5)
```

Its better to post a sqlfiddle for us to work with.